# How to get more physical details when executing an SQL query?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, execution-plan, deadlock, query-performance

I want to get some physical features about a SQL query execution with PostgreSQL, like

- Read/write page accesses
- I/O operations
- Response time
- Sequential I/O throughput rate
- Deadlocks
- Pages scanned Queries ratio
- Hit ratio, Pages read, Logging, Ratio of using indexes Rows selected , Average sort time, Number of locks held, Number of sorts Throughput..

and more, depends on what's available

Comment: turn on track_io_timing and run `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `pg_stat_statements`.

Modify `postgresql.conf` as follows:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
track_io_timing = on
```

and restart PostgreSQL.

Then

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

and find all the data you want in the view `pg_stat_statements`.

Comment: Can I use a view instead of an extension?

Comment: The extension creates the view. But the important part is the data collection, which is triggered by adding the module to `shared_preload_libraries`.

Comment: I am using Postgres-XL, I cannot create an extension there and I am looking for more information like Hit ratio,... I am trying so hard to make pg_stat_statements works but I am getting things like ```HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts``` , the 3 lines are added in the coordinator postgres.conf

Comment: I have no idea if `pg_stat_statements` works on Postgres-XL.